# Error: R studio not running, shinytheme (theme) yeti is not available theme

Tags: r

I am trying to edit my data using DataEditR package. I have used the R built in dataset to reproduce the problem I am facing with my data. Whenever I use data_edit() function, the error message pops up saying Error: RStudio not running
Error in shinytheme(theme) : yeti is not an available theme. Valid themes are: .

I am not sure what the problem is, could you please help me out? Thanks in advance

```
library(help = "datasets")
    # load dataset esoph--
    data("esoph")
    head("esoph")
    #> [1] "esoph"
    #> [1] "esoph"
    # load library DataEditR
    library('DataEditR')
    data_edit(esoph)
    #> Error: RStudio not running
    #>Error in shinytheme(theme) : 
      yeti is not an available theme. Valid themes are: .
```

Comment: Just to ask the obvious, you are running this code in the RStudio console window?

Comment: I am running them in the RStudio Command window.

Comment: I've verified that it works for me on a Mac using latest versions of R and RStudio. Have you tried uninstalling it, reinstalling it, and re-starting your R session?

Comment: Thank you. I did try all reinstalling and also restarting the session but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I am using R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)

Comment: I figured it out. I installed Rtools and added them to Renvir and then it worked for the R inbuilt data. But I now have a different problem when I am applying it to my data. A lengthy error message is popping up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In RStudio for Window, I had an similar error.
"cerulean is not an available theme. Valid themes are: . "

By updating RStudio version from RStudio-2022.02.0-443.exe to RStudio-2022.02.1-461,
the error has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in the shinytheme package used to look up all "*.min.css" theme files. Unfortunately there is an issue with regex in RStudio-2022.02.0-443, hence these *css files included in the shinytheme package cannot be found. This issue was fixed in the later version of Rstudio.

This issue has been documented [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/10679)